# Stuck w/ xterm on Xfce

Tags: debian, terminal, xfce, desktop, terminal-emulator

I want to run a terminal application and created a desktop entry in `/usr/share/applications`. For some reason, `Terminal=true` in the entry fires up `xterm` even though:

- `TERM=x-terminal-emulator`
- `exo-preferred-applications` displays "Debian X Terminal Emulator"
- `exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator` launches `xfce4-terminal`
- `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` shows `xfce4-terminal.wrapper` as selected

What's the problem, what launches up `xterm`, where is this defined? I'm on Xfce on Debian stable

Comment: If you open "Default Applications" in your Settings Manager (or "Preferred Applications" for older Xfce versions), what's selected in the drop-down list under "Terminal Emulator" on the "Utilities" tab?

Comment: @DavidYockey This is the output of `exo-preferred-applications`